# Angular App Empty Page in IE but works in Chrome

Tags: angular

I have started learning `Angular 4` and wrote a default application using `Angular CLI (NG New HelloWorld)`. When i write `ng serve`, and browse to `http://localhost:4200/`, the page loads fine in `Chrome`, However in `IE-Edge`, it opens up as an empty page. there is an error in the console window of IE which is `SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught
File: polyfills.bundle.js, Line: 859, Column: 36`. 
Is this expected?

`Screenshot of Empty Page in Internet Explorer`

[image: Internet Explorer = Edge]

`Screenshot of How it loads in Chrome`

[image: Chrome]

Comment: probably not normal... are there any console errors reported from the debug tools?

Comment: sorry yes there is an error thrown in the console window: Exception thrown and not caught: polyfills.bundle.js

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: SCRIPT5022: Exception thrown and not caught
File: polyfills.bundle.js, Line: 859, Column: 36

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found my answer here: [Angular4 Application running issues in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353619/angular4-application-running-issues-in-ie11).

Go to `polyfills.ts` file under the `src/` folder and then as per the instructions in that file, uncomment (or add if there aren't these lines) the following lines:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

#### Final notes

For the newer versions of [core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) you need to change the `import` from `'…/es6/…'` to `'…/es/…'` (example: `import 'core-js/es/symbol';`).

Comment: I also had to put `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` in the header of `index.html`

Comment: And it's polyfills.ts it's not in the js file

Comment: I uncommented the pollyfills and even tried adding meta in index.html but I am still facing same issue.

Answer (score 22):

I'm running angular 8 application in windows 10 with IE11.

I tried many solutions from stackoverflow. But didn't worked anything. then i tried same solutions separately, then i got to one conclusion.

This is my final solution. i don't for howmany people it will work. but for me it worked.

**1. tsconfig.json**

```
"target": "es2015"
```

changed to

```
"target": "es5"
```

**2. Restart your applications. this Mandatory.**

Comment: The localhost app started working after adding the polyfills and changing the target variable as you stated above.
Just letting you know - thanks!

Comment: To add, es2015 (es6) is not supported by IE hence the blank page issue.

Answer (score 5):

step 1:

```
Include or uncomment the below lines in pollyfills.ts below which is under src folder


> import 'classlist.js';  import 'web-animations-js'; (window as
> any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true; import
> 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Step 2:

```
Run `npm install --save classlist.js`. 
Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

Step 3:change the value of target from es2015 to es5 in your tsconfig.json file as below

> "target": "es5",

Step 4:

```
Restart your application by doing ng serve
```

Comment: One more step- You need to also remove 'not' from 'not IE 9-11' in browserlist file.

Answer (score 1):

what is your ie version.

at official site it's only support 9,10,11

see more : https://angular.io/guide/browser-support