# What is the right way to integrate polyfills to make Angular compatible with Internet Explorer?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, web-component, polyfills

I develop a client-side graphical interface with Angular. Users of the application must be able to view the graphical interface from **Internet Explorer**. The problem is that Internet Explorer doesn't display anything, just a **blank page**. Other browsers correctly display the Angular application. I know I have to use polyfills to do this but all my attempts with the polyfills have failed. So, what is the right way to do it?

I work with **Angular 8**, **NodeJS v10.15.3** and my Angular application implements some **web components** and the **Angular router**. I did some research on the subject and by cross-checking the different information I found I was able to write the polyfills.ts file which seems to me to be quite correct according to the following:

[Angular App Empty Page in IE but works in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46657410/angular-app-empty-page-in-ie-but-works-in-chrome)

https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-and-internet-explorer-5e59bb6fb4e9

[IE11 empty page using Angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282982/ie11-empty-page-using-angular-7)

https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#suggested-polyfills

So, my polyfills.ts file looks like this:

```js
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

import 'classlist.js';

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/array';

import 'web-animations-js';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

/* for web components */
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/native-shim';
import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min';
```

I expected Internet Explorer to display my content but... no.

Before I add polyfills I've got a blank page. After I've got a blank page but this time with errors inside the console which are not errors:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!ArJSYka9gM27oknTCiu7v0UohOFb

I also tried with "polyfills.io" API but it wasn't really conclusive.

I certainly must have forgotten something in the configurations or the polyfills just don't work? Anyway, I'm stuck for the moment and I hope some of you can help me. Thank you in advance for your feedback, have a good day.

Comment: Try to run your app with --prod flag or like ng serve --live-reload false It may help to run the app in IE. Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9508

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT it doesn't change anything, always a blank page with the same errors (both flags).

Comment: Please check your tsconfig.json file and ensure that target is set to ES5 and not to ES6. Also ensure that you had referenced shim.min.js in your index.html file.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks ! I just change es2015 to es5 and now IE displays my app. Is there a good way to reference shim.min.js inside index.html file ? Because put "../node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/src/shim.min" inside a script tag seems to me a strange way.

Comment: From your last comment, It looks like your issue is solved. I suggest you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer for this question may help other community members in future in similar issues. thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your tsconfig.json file and ensure that target is set to ES5 and not to ES6. Also ensure that you had referenced shim.min.js in your index.html file.

about shim.min.js, I also got the same way to reference it.