# angular cli and Internet Explorer, what is the cons of uncommenting polyfills.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer-11

I had the same issue as in [Angular4 Application running issues in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45353619/angular4-application-running-issues-in-ie11)
and the solution does solve the problem at hand, but I could not figure out why these lines ( IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills ) were commented to begin with ?
What are the disadvantage of un-commenting the section in polyfills.ts

Answer (score 0):

I believe the disadvantage would be that the bundle size becomes larger.